# Property seems to reassign to null after I set it in another class

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
namespace Contacts
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    AddNewContact contact = new AddNewContact();

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        //BindingContext = contactTable;

        //contactName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(contactTable.Name)));
        // contactList.Text = contact.Name;

    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();


        DisplayAlert("error", contact.Name, "OK"); 
        //Why is the name property of the AddNewContact class resetting
        //from the name I entered into the Entry?
    }
```

and here is the AddNewContact class where I set the Name property.

```
public partial class AddNewContact : ContentPage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AddNewContact()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void SaveContact(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Name = entryName.Text;
        DisplayAlert("Contact saved", "You have successfully saved the contact", "OK");
    }
```

I want to display the AddNewContact.name in the MainPage.xaml rather than the AddNewContact.xaml?

Comment: Can you please post a more complete sample of your code and explain in greater detail?
Where do you call the SaveContact method? (From the code you supplied it seems like the only place where the Name property is set)

Answer (score 0):

Add new contact and main page appear to me as different views / view models.

Generally, it depends on how you are using this value in your application.

**Option 1:**
You can raise an event from AddnewContact SaveContact method to "MainPage" view model. 
That should set a local property in MainPage.xaml.

Then it should be displayed. 
If you are using Caliburn.Micro then you can refer EventAggregator samples to understand how events are used in Caliburn based MVVM.

OR

**Option 2:**
You can have a context object which is applicable to all view / view models (something like current user session).   You can add this value in the context and then access it from MainPage.

Please note this will work only if Main Page accesses value after it was set from AddNewContact page.